# Populating protobuf fields in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, protocol-buffers

In a codebase I see some protobuf definition as

```
message Foo {
repeated FooData foo_data = 1;
}
```

Later on these protobufs are used in a C++ method in the following way

```
auto& bar = *protobuf_foo.add_foo_data();
```

but I don't see `add_foo_data()` defined anywhere. Is this a protobuf property that prepending `add_` and adding parentheses at the end is some sort of reserved syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method comes from c++ code generated from protobuf definitions.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated